# Altium Designer - Method for changing the size of multiple pads at the same time

Tags: altium

I want to edit multiple pads at the same time to have the same dimensions. I have tried selecting multiple pads and editing one of them, but that only changes the selected pad.

Is there a method for editing multiple pads at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Find Similar Objects" is your friend. Right click on one of the pads and choose options to select the desired pads, click "Apply" & "OK" then change the parameter you want to alter and they will all change.

Note that "Selected" is one of the options if you prefer to pre-select the pads.